# How to have two divs side by side and keep aspect ration same on all dimensions?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically the title says it all.

How do I have two divs next to each other, and when on a different sized screen ( lets say smaller ) they don't merge into one, and if there is not enough space to go down to the next line? Also if possible to scale down the elements inside ( text and image and button )

Thank you!

CURRENT PAGE WITH PROBLEM (The giveaway boxes are the dicvs btw):

[Here](http://newsite.001a.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a class with float:left in it for both. 
And use margin to center them as you want instead of your margin-left:50%.

Something like :

```
    .giveaway {
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    width: 360px;
    height: 325px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #336699;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 25px;
}

.giveaway1 {
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    width: 360px;
    height: 325px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #336699;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 25px;
}
```

you should use the same class for both by the way...

Comment: Thank you! That works, but it they are not centered. It looks a little odd as they are slightly off to the left of the rest of the site.

Comment: it's because your main section have a width 50% of the screen and your giveway div have a width fix of 360px. So as the windows get smaller, your giveway div become larger the your main section. You should use media query to make things works

Comment: Thank you! I just played around with the body width, and it seems to be okay for now!

Answer (score 0):

I used a wrapper div to contain and center the two smaller divs. Then just used a media query to make them block level at a certain window width (for smaller screens)

Of course, you can adjust the widths / @media rule to suit your own needs

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#page-wrapper {
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
}
.box {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}
@media(max-width: 650px) {
    .box {
        width: auto;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="box">
        <p>Stuff goes here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <p>Stuff goes here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```